# Error :jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version

Tags: java, kotlin, sdk, jvm

im new to android . while running module i got following error :

Execution failed for task ':info:compileKotlin'.

> 'compileJava' task (current target is 1.7) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

please gimme solution

I tried in project structure to change gradle plugin. and gradle jdk but nothing has happened

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle files ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to fix this by using below code

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate{
        tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
            if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") || project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
                kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility
            } else {
                kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = sourceCompatibility
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering indicates that there's a mismatch between the Java target versions set for the `compileJava` task and the `compileKotlin` task in your Gradle project. To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that both tasks are configured to use the same Java version.

According to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk7-naming.html, in JDK 7 and JRE 7, the version strings are 1.7 and 1.7.0, so you should use '1.7' as the Kotlin compile target not '17'!

I think it should be like this:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.7'
}
```